# I want to export a table's data into excel sheet in django i have done the exact thing and written the code for it but getting FieldError

Tags: python, django, excel, database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMiJg.png)here is my views.py

this code is for exporting to excel sheet

```
    def export_excel(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="candidates.xls"'
 
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet('candidates') 
    # Sheet header, first row
    row_num = 0
 
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.font.bold = True
 
    columns = ['Full Name ', 'Email', 'Notice Period (in Days)', 'Current Location', 'Expected Location', 'Current CTC (Per Annum)', 'Expected CTC (Per Annum)', 'Upload CV', ' Gender']
 
    for col_num in range(len(columns)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)
 
    # Sheet body, remaining rows
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
 
    rows = ApplyForm.objects.all().values_list('full_name', 'email', 'noticeperiod', 'preferredlocation', ' expectedlocation', 'currentctc', ' expectedctc', ' cv', 'gender' )
    for row in rows:
        row_num += 1
        for col_num in range(len(row)):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)
 
    wb.save(response)
    return response
```

this is the code for filling up the form and submitting to databasein views.py

```
def applyform(request):
    data = ApplyForm.objects.all()
    print(data)

    if request.method == "POST":
        full_name = request.POST['full_name']
        email = request.POST['email']
        noticeperiod = request.POST['noticeperiod']
        preferredlocation = request.POST['preferredlocation']
        expectedlocation = request.POST['expectedlocation']
        currentctc = request.POST['currentctc']
        expectedctc= request.POST['expectedctc']
        gender = request.POST['gender']
        cv = request.FILES['cv']
        
        ins = ApplyForm(full_name = full_name, email = email,  noticeperiod = noticeperiod, preferredlocation = preferredlocation, expectedlocation= expectedlocation, currentctc =currentctc, expectedctc = expectedctc, gender = gender, cv = cv)
        ins.save()
        print("the data has been written to the db")
```

here is my models.py

```
class ApplyForm(models.Model):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=300)
    noticeperiod = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    preferredlocation = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    expectedlocation = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    currentctc = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    expectedctc = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    cv = models.FileField(upload_to='')
```

I am getting an error of FieldError but all the fields are correct I have checked many times tried to resolve this I want just to export my table in excel sheet where all the data are coming from the database. I have been trying for a long time but couldn't resolve.

Comment: You have a typo. It must be **'expectedlocation'** not **' expectedlocation'**. You have white space at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks a lot it solved my problem.

Comment: I have a another question I have uploaded a pdf also which is in my media folder I want to get the pdf in the excel sheet as I am getting the other fields but only the name of the pdf is exporting but not the actual file

Comment: Have you tried: **cv.name**?

Comment: No but where to put it the html table which I have created and in the cv column I am getting the pdfs and it is downloadable and the same name of the pdf is also in the database. But want that exact pdf file in my excel sheet when I am querying.

Comment: all pdf files are there in media folder and in the column cv of database only the name of pdf is there like sample.pdf and I am querying the database and exporting into excel sheet but not getting the actual pdf file